# I can't upload 2 files using multer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, multer

I Have 2 files( 1 video and 1 image ) and i want to upload it to my server using multer
This is my react code :

```js
const data = new FormData();
data.append('banner', this.state.banner);
data.append('preview', this.state.preview);

axios.post('/lesson', data).then(() => {})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="file" id='file1' onChange={this.handleUploadFile1} />
  
  <input type="file" id='file2' onChange={this.handleUploadFile2} />
</div>
```

And here is my server code :

```
router.post('/lesson', upload.single('banner'), upload.single('preview'),controller.addLesson)
```

Then i got this error :

> MulterError: Unexpected field

Please help me how i can solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `upload.any()` or `upload.array()` instead of `upload.single()`.

Also, you can do something like this:

```
let multerWithFields = upload.fields([{ name: 'banner', maxCount: 1 }, { name: 'preview', maxCount: 1 }]) 
router.post('/lesson', multerWithFields, controller.addLesson)
```

[See the docs](https://github.com/expressjs/multer).

Comment: Please help me out here if you can..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55716774/multer-unexpected-field-even-field-names-are-same